# Circle's area using lenght of the side of the square ascribed in the circle / C++

Tags: c++

I've written this C++ code which is supposed to compute circles' areas using the length of the side of the square inscribed in the circle. I get no errors but the result isn't right. Any advice?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float l, ac, r, area;
    cout << "Square's side length: ";
    cin >> l;
    ac = l * sqrt(2);
    r = ac/2;
    area = M_PI * pow(2,r);
    cout << "Circle's area: "<<area<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is the result not right?

Comment: Did you mean `pow(r, 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

In computing the area you have to write `area = M_PI * pow(r,2);`: you just inverted the arguments of the `pow` function.

Answer (score 0):

The diameter of the circle would be equal to the hypotenuse of the diagonal of the square, so assuming `l` is side length of the square

```
float diam = std::sqrt(2.0f * std::pow(l, 2));
float radius = diam / 2.0f;
float area = M_PI * std::pow(radius, 2.0f);
```

Comment: Yes, I inverted the arguments of the pow function